# Dynamic action construction 

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a basic JSF question. I have a loop where I am trying to create mutile command link depending on the list value. and that command link will call the corresponding action from the list filed.

Basically I have this bean:

```
public class FavoriteTasks implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8702569738872927728L;

    private String key;
    private String action;
    private String widget;
    private String name;

    public FavoriteTasks(String key, String action, String widget, String name) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.action = action;
        this.widget = widget;

    }
```

And then populating it using properties file:

```
    private void setUpFavTasks(UserUIPreferencesVO uiPref) {
    List<String> fTaskList = uiPref.getFavoriteTasks();
     favTasks =new ArrayList<FavoriteTasks>();
    for(String var:fTaskList){
        FavoriteTasks ft = new FavoriteTasks(var,
                ConfigurationData.getValue(var+".action"),
                ConfigurationData.getValue(var+".widget"),
                ConfigurationData.getValue(var+".name"));
        favTasks.add(ft);
    }

}
```

Now the issue is the action is not understanding that it needs to get the value first and read that and then make the method call depending on the value.

```
        <ui:repeat value="#{userSessionBean.favTasks}" var="favTasks" >
            <li><ice:commandLink styleClass="shortcut-menu" action="#{favTasks.action}">                  
               <f:param name="filterByContentWidget" value="#{favTasks.widget}" />
               <f:param name="filterByContentGroup" value="#{favTasks.key}" />
               <f:param name="menuName" value="#{favTasks.name}" />       
               <h:outputText value="#{msgs[favTasks.key]}" /> 
            </ice:commandLink>
            </li>
    </ui:repeat>
```

action is trying to get favTasks.action and failing as there are no such method. it needs to read the value stored in favTasks.action and then go to the method that value is saying... for example if the favTasks.action = catalogHandler.showCatalog. it needs to invoke catalogHandler.showCatalog not favTasks.action

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute is used to indicate the next view when you click the commandLink. It is a method expression that returns a String.

For example:

```
public String method() {
   //do something
   return "success";
}
```

and in your commandLink as

```
<ice:commandLink value="Submit" action="#{bean.method}" />
```

when clicked will take you to success.xhtml

Also you need to declare public setters/getters you just can't get/set any private variables that you have in your code:

```
private String key;
private String widget;
private String name;
```